Prevent build events from running multiple times across referenced projects in Visual Studio 2019
I am using Visual Studio 2019, and I have a solution where a project references other projects.
Each project has custom build events defined that run an external .exe file. For example, in the Post-build events, I call:
if $(ConfigurationName) == Release "path\to\myExecutable.exe"

The issue is that when I build the main project (the one I selected as the Startup Project), Visual Studio builds all the referenced projects as well (if needed). During this process, the build events in each referenced project are triggered, causing my .exe to run multiple times—once for each project.
What I want to achieve is:
Keep the build events in all projects (because they might be useful if I build them independently).
Run the .exe only once during a solution build, but only for the Startup Project.
How can I configure Visual Studio to execute the build event only for the Startup Project while keeping the build events intact for other projects?
Thank you!
